# How can I encrypt a 128Gb SD Card in Sierra (10.12.6)

Tags: macos, partition, encryption, sd-card

[image]I cannot erase a MicroSOCX SD Card (128GB) using a GUID partition map. I only get errors. Without a GUID map, I cannot partition either.

I have tried it on both the main volume and the dependent container (actually, only the main container gives a GUID option in the Erase popup menu. I have tried a contextual menu click on the mounted volume which has an Encrypt option but fails with the error saying that it needs to be in GUID format.

1/3 Got the SD Card to GUID map, Partition, and encrypt. Not sure how I did it- I just kept trying and suddenly it worked! Two days ago I did a level 5 erase on the chip- that may have helped. Good luck and sorry I can't give any definitive info.

I have searched everywhere and the problem seems to be in El Capitan and Sierra, and USB sticks and such seem to be OK.

I do not wish to upgrade my Mac, as I'm doing just fine on Sierra.

MBP Late 2013.

Comment: Can you provide the errors you get?

Comment: I added an image. I haven't tried the operation in Terminal.

Comment: And what are the details under "Show Details"?